# Mapping turtles variables to patches

Tags: variables, netlogo

I have created for each turtle a variable `utilities` (utility assigned to a patch (school)) containing 30 values derived from `school-utility` (reporter), one for each patch (school). Each turtle has 30 values on this variable. I then created the cumulative sum for each turtle.

```
to utility
  set utilities [ school-utility ] of patches with [ schoolachievement_2 > 0 ]
  set  cumul sum utilities
  let temp utilities
  set  school-utility_1  map [ i -> i / cumul ] temp
  set school-utility_1  sort school-utility_1


  let cum-sum []
  let sum-so-far 0
  let index 0
  foreach school-utility_1 [
    let next-sum sum-so-far + item index school-utility_1
    set cum-sum lput next-sum cum-sum
    set sum-so-far next-sum
    set index index + 1
  ]
  set cum-utility_1 cum-sum
```

I am trying to make turtles select the patch (school) which minimises the difference between `random-number 0 + random-float 1` and `cum-utility_1`. The problem is that `cum-utility_1` is a turtle variable.

I have tried

```
set targets patches with <....>
    let min-patch  min-one-of targets [abs (random-number - [ cum-utility_1] of myself)]
```

but I get the message `- expected input to be a number but got the list...`.

I also tried

```
set targets patches with <....>
    let min-patch  min-one-of targets [abs (random-number - cum-utility_1)]
```

getting `this code can't be run by a patch, only a turtle...` I suspect that issue is that Netlogo does not know how to map the different values of `cum-utility_1` to each patch (school).

Comment: Nic, Am I right to assume that the "set targets ..." code is being run by each turtle?  And since cum-utility-1 has nothing specific to a particular patch, it's not clear how your code is going to select a particular patch. Can you go through the steps that will identify a particular patch from its own school-utility value?

Comment: Dear @Charles, thank you. Yes, `set targets ..` is being run by each turtle. `cum-utility_1` is specific to a particular patch (school) in that each turtle has a value for every patch (school, 30 schools in total). Now I have 30 patch specific values in `cum-utility_1`, but I do not know to which patch they belong to. Perhaps I could try to associate each value to a patch id that I generate, but I am not sure. I am not sure I have made things clearer. Thank you.

Comment: The error says it all. `cum-utility_1` is a list and not a number, so you can't just substract it. You should first figure out which value of `cum-utility_1` you want to utilise. It is the highest value? The mean? The sum of them all?
I also assume that `cum-utility_1` is different for all turtles? So yes, if you want to know which value is linked to which patch you will need to add in some extras. This could be with a second list that records this, or maybe with links (But that can get big very quickly)

Comment: Dear @LeirsW, thanks for the response and the explanation. Yes `cum-utility_1` is different for all turtles. What I need is to select the value of `cum-utility_1` that is closer to the random number (hence the attempt to minimise the difference). Thank you for pointing out that the command does not do that what I need. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you, Nic

Comment: Nic, Then I think you need to back up and redefine the lists that contain values specific to each patch to maintain an association between the patch and the value.  As @LiersW suggests, that can be done with links, but with 30 schools and perhaps 100's of students, the number of links explodes pretty rapidly.  Let me work up an example of how that might be done with lists.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one approach to each turtle needing to link utilities to patches.  It uses lists of lists, where the first element of each sublist is the patch (school) and the second is some value related to that patch.  Lists of lists are a bit tricky, but not so bad once you get used to them. Note that my `school-utility` reporter is simply illustrative, but it does contain variables from both the patch and the turtle, as I gather yours does.  Note too that `random-number 0 + random-float 1` is not a valid syntax, so I interpreted it to mean that `random-number` was the random number you wanted to subtract each `cum-utility` from.  Finally, I can't test this code without embedding it in a larger model, so there may be syntax errors I haven't caught.

```
;school-utility should return a list of lists, of the form [[patch value] [patch value] ...]
;For instance:
to-report school-utility
  report list self (school-achievement_2 * [some-variable] of myself)
end

;Then,

to utility
  set utilities [ school-utility ] of patches with [ schoolachievement_2 > 0 ]
  set  cumul sum map [i -> last i] utilities
  set  school-utility_1  map [ i -> list (first i) (last i / cumul) ] utilities
  set school-utility_1  sort-by [[i j] -> last i < last j] school-utility_1

;Now we have the patches sorted by their utilities, with the first item in each
;sublist being the patch and the second (last) being the utility.

  let cum-sum []
  let sum-so-far 0
  foreach school-utility_1 [i ->
    let next-sum sum-so-far + last i
;for a simple list without patch links
    set cum-sum lput next-sum cum-sum
;for a list with patch links, which is what you will want below
    set cum-sum lput list first i cum-sum
    set sum-so-far next-sum
  ]
  set cum-utility_1 cum-sum
;I think that last cum-utility_1 = 1.0?
  
  let random-number random-float 1
  let possible-targets map [i -> list first i abs (random-number - last i)]
;Now we want to find the sublist in possible targets with the minimum value for its
;second (last) element. target will be the first item in the first
;sublist of the sorted possible-targets.
  set target first first sort-by [[i j] -> last i < last j] possible-targets

end
```

I'm thinking that using links may not be so bad as @LeirsW and I initially thought.  I may play around with that a bit.

Comment: Dear @Charles LeirsW, I am trying to add a comment but the number of characters allowed is not enough.....

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to the problem using links.  Instead of permanent links, each student creates links to potential schools during the search process and then deletes them.  There is some overhead to this, but the number of links at any given time remains small. And, since there is a single link between the student and each potential school, the link can hold those variables specific to each student/school pair. However, there is a catch. NetLogo does not allow links between turtles and patches, so we have had to make schools a breed of turtles that then sit on a patch. This is actually a better approach since a patch is a location, whereas a school is an entity that has location as one, but just one of its attributes.  Since schools are then a breed of turtles, it makes sense to give students their own breed too.

Again, without the full model I have not been able to test this for accuracy or speed.

```
breed [schools school]
breed [students student]
links-own [school-utility_1 cum-utility_1 target-value]
students-own [some-variable target]
schools-own [school-achievement_2]

to-report school-utility 
  ; Since these are directed links created by
  ; students, they run from student (end1) to school (end2).
  report ([school-achievement_2] of end2 * [some-variable] of end1)
end

to utility ; this is run by turtles (students)
  ; create links to possible targets (schools) and have each link 
  ; determine the utility of that school.
  let possible-targets schools with [school-achievement_2 > 0]
  create-links-to possible-targets [
    set school-utility_1 school-utility 
  ]
  
  ; sum the utilties of all the possible schools
  let cumul sum [school-utility_1] of my-out-links
  ; calculate the school utilities relative to the total
  ask my-out-links [set school-utility_1 school-utility_1 / cumul]
  
  ; now sort the links by school-utility_1.  
  ; this gives us a list of links to the schools.
  let sorted-links sort-on [school-utility_1] my-out-links
  ; and build the cum-utility_1 values
  let sum-so-far 0
  foreach sorted-links [i ->
    let next-sum sum-so-far + [school-utility_1] of i
    ask i [set cum-utility_1 next-sum]
    set sum-so-far next-sum
  ]
  
  ; now find the target.
  ; We want to find the link, and thus the school, with the minimum calculated value.
  let random-number random-float 1
  ask my-out-links [
    set target-value abs (random-number - cum-utility_1)
  ]
  set target [end2] of min-one-of my-out-links [target-value]
  
  ; finally, clean up
  ask my-out-links [ die ]
  
end
```